# Быстрый поиск как по ключу, так и по значению

Tags: c#, .net

Понимаю,что само название вопроса звучит абсурдно.Есть коллекция объектов `FileInfo`.Нужно искать со сложностью **O(1)** или **O(log n)** иногда по имени,а иногда по хешу. Хеши уникальны, а вот имена нет

```
public class FileInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Один Dictionary и один Lookup. Один раз заполняете обе коллекции, потом ищете хоть там, хоть там.

Comment: Отличная идея с Lookup, но коллекция изменяется

Comment: Есть (вернее, была) такая вещь: [index for objects](https://github.com/ericksoa/i4o). Давно не поддерживается, но выглядит интересно.

Comment: @МаксимГорностаев: Ну и что, что изменяется? При изменении нужно передобавлять элемент в обе коллекции, итоговая сложность всё равно O(1).

Comment: @VladD, Если найдете в Lookup метод Add или Push, то так и сделаю

Comment: @МаксимГорностаев: Ну вы придираетесь. Возьмите вместо Lookup `Dictionary<Key, IGrouping<Key, Value>>` или там вообще `Dictionary<Key, IGrouping<Key, Value>>` (как в ответе). Lookup — это структура данных только для чтения, да.

Comment: @VladD, пока так и сделал. Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, FileInfo>>. Жду еще предложений

Answer (score 2):

Делаете один словарь на `Dictionary<string,FileInfo>`, а второй делаете на `Dictionary<string,List<FileInfo>>`-для не уникальных имен.

Получается, что в первом случае вам вернется конкретный `FileInfo`, а во втором случае вы получите конкретный список `FileInfo`.

Или можно сделать 1 словарь `Dictionary<string,Object>` и задекорировать его в какой-нибудь класс, что бы поддерживать 1 коллекцию, и дергать метод `GetByName` и получать `List<FileInfo>` или `GetByHash` и получать `FileInfo`.

По идее, должно шустро работать. Другого решения что-то на ум не приходит.

Comment: За что минус? Поясните.

Comment: Да, я тоже думаю сделать именно так.

Comment: Если не будет каких-нибудь предложений лучше, поставлю лучший ответ